# Mapping entity without any key

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate

I've got two tables in database: Table A (parent) has a primary key column and Table B (child) doesn't have a key at all, but references to the key in table A (parent).

The column aID (not a primary/foreign key) refererences to the id in table A (parent).

[image]

I've tried to use a composite key in table B, but without any success:

**Mappings:**

```
 public AMap() 
 {
    Id(a=> a.Id);
    Map(a=> a.Name);
    HasMany(a=> a.B)
       .Cascade.All();
 }

 public BMap() 
 {
    CompositeId()
       .KeyReference(b=> b.A, "aID");
    Map(b=> b.Name);
    Map(b=> b.Year);
 }
```

**Entity A properties:**

```
 public virtual int Id { get; set; }
 public virtual string Name { get; set; }
 public virtual IList<B> B { get; set; }
```

**Entity B properties:**

```
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Year { get; set; }
```

**I've also tried components:**

```
 public AMap() 
 {
    HasMany<B>(a => a.B)
        .Component(b =>
        {
           b.References<A>(bb=> bb.A).Fetch.Join();
         //b.Map(bb => bb.A).Column("aID");
           b.Map(bb => bb.Name);
           b.Map(bb => bb.Year);
        })
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.All();
 }
```

But then i get following exceptions:

Inner exception: NHibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: TestProject.Test.A.B column: A_id

The B list does not get populated when im getting all a:s from database, does anyone see something wrong in this code or have a better solution than using a Composite key ? Is it possible to let nhibernate use an identifier only in application layer ?
I'm not able to change data model in database.

EDIT: Added new exception occured, changed to auto properties.

Comment: it will probably be easier to add a new primary key (ID column) and a foreign key relationship on aID to Table B

Comment: I totally agree, but this is only a sandbox project and a reproduction of the real project where i'm not able to add any keys or change something because whole system is depending on that the database look like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it with:

```
 public AMap() 
 {
    ....
    ....
    HasMany(a=> a.B).KeyColumn("aID").Inverse().Cascade.All();
 }

 public BMap()
 {
   CompositeId()
         .KeyProperty(b=> b.AID)
         .KeyProperty(b=> b.Name)
         .KeyProperty(b=> b.Year);
   References(b=> b.A).Column("aID");
   Map(b=> b.Name);
   Map(b=> b.Year);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a component but , you should use a collection of components. 
See : [component collection mapping NHibernate 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190773/component-collection-mapping-nhibernate-3-2)

Comment: Im using fluent nhibernate 1.4.0.0 and nhibernate 3.3.3.4001. Im not able to use Bag.

Comment: This is my opinion but I would avoid using fluent nhibernate and just use mapping by code.

Answer (score 0):

You should drop the AID property from Entity B and just use:

```
public BMap() 
{
    Map(b=> b.Name);
    Map(b=> b.Year);
    References(b => b.A).Column("aID");
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#wiki-references--many-to-one) for more information.

Comment: I see that you've now dropped the AID property, but you haven't tried the simple `References` mapping.  In your question, you say you've tried `CompositeID/KeyReference` and a components approach.

Comment: I think I have already tried what you say also. But i will try it again to be sure. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, i've tried it before except i also used Id().Column("aID"). The exception that occurs: Invalid column name 'A_id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'A_id'.

Comment: Are you sure?  The `.Column` directive is supposed to let you tell nhibernate exactly which column to work with, instead of letting it decide based on some convention (which appears to be the case with that error)

Comment: Id().Column("aID");
            References(b => b.A).Column("aID");
            Map(b => b.Name);
            Map(b => b.Year);

Comment: Take out the `Id` directive.  `aID` is *not* an Id for this object!  Leave in the `References` directive only.

Comment: As the mapping class extends ClassMap<B> i need to have Id, else i get this exception ---> FluentNHibernate.Visitors.ValidationException: The entity B doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id).

Comment: I see.  Then records from the B table cannot act as entities with their own lifecycle and can only act as components of As (as indicated in other answers).  If this is the case, then there is no reason to provide a reference from B to A (as the only way to discover a B in the first place is via an A).

Comment: Yeah, B table does not have any key column at all. It just got a field with Id, that the system in turn does stuff with. But i need to store B's to the database when i store A's to database. And the only way to get B is to go through A.

Comment: Yep, sounds like a component mapping is the way to go.